# Android Magento Ksoap2 get Category image

Tags: android, magento, ksoap2

Currently i am Working for Android Magento api integration.For that i am using Ksoap2 library to parse Soap Response in android...i m having trouble to get category image..
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html

i used "catalogCategoryInfo" method to get specific category information.
And getting response like this:

```
catalogCategoryInfo{category_id=3; is_active=1; position=1; level=2; parent_id=2; all_children=3; children=; created_at=2014-07-31T17:43:35+05:30; updated_at=2014-11-24 06:38:01; name=Wedding Collections; url_key=t-shirt; path=1/2/3; url_path=t-shirt.html; children_count=0; display_mode=PRODUCTS; is_anchor=0; available_sort_by=ArrayOfString{}; default_sort_by=position; }
```

there is no field like "image"(in SOAP v1 response "image" field is available.see above url). i checked responseobject.getPropertyCount() for total number of attributes..but getting only 18 attributes.
how can i get category image url?